# Validar una lista de nombres con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo una función que recibe una lista de nombres para validar: ejm:

```
const list = ['Daniel', 'Jose', '(George)', '(Ivan', '()'].
```

Debo retornar true: si la lista esta escrita correctamente. que si tienen paréntesis, que cierren correctamente y tampoco existan vacíos '()', y que tampoco tengan llaves ni corchetes.
Ejm:

```
const list = ['Daniel', 'José', '(George)'] //true
const list = ['Daniel', 'Jose', '(George)', '(Ivan', '()'] // false
```

Generé el código para generar la lista correcta, solo tengo problemas para validar este caso ')name(', ya que me retorna true.

```
const list = ['Daniel', 'Jose', '(George)', '(Ivan', '()'];

function isValid(listWords) {
  let res = true;
  if (listWords[0][0] === ')') res = false;

  listWords.forEach((word) => {
    if (
      word[0] === '(' &&
      (word[word.length - 1] !== ')' ||
        word.includes('{') ||
        word.includes('[') ||
        word.includes(']') ||
        word.slice(1, word.length).includes('(') ||
        word.length <= 2)
    )
      res = false;
  });

  return res;
}

console.log(isValid(list));
```

Comment: La linea  `if(listWords[0][0] === ')') res = false;` carece de sentido (solo estás probando la primera letra de la primera palabra, deberías probar la primera letra de TODAS las palabras). Por favor, borra esta línea. Agrega dentro de tu foreach `if (word[0] === ')') res = false;`. Con eso solucionarás tu problema.

Comment: Tampoco queda claro los casos posibles. ¿Es `(Ivan)))` un caso posible? ¿Y qué tal `((Ivan))`¿ ¿Debería ser true por estar balanceado?. Actualmente tu función no maneja para nada estos escenarios.

Comment: Si el caso valido solo es para (Ivan), etc como sería el script en los demás casos que mencionaste ?

Comment: @Cris223511.dev para estos casos '(Daniel)))', sigue dando true, cuando debería ser false

Comment: @JaimeMenendez buscaba una manera de hacerlo sin usar regex, pero creo que es la única forma de llegar a la solución con expresiones regulares.

Comment: es que incluso eliminando el caso de los parentesis balanceado, la funcion sigue sin rechazar simbolos como ?!%$ y muchos otros casos. Deja ver si pienso en un caso sin regex y edito mi respuesta, pero creo que esta por ahora es tu mejor opcion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si como dices, un nombre solo es válido cuando está escrito con letras `Nombre` o cuando está en formato `(Nombre)` una posible solución sería construir una expresión regular para testear cada nombre.

- El nombre solo será válido si empieza y termina por más de una letra de la A a la Z sin acento: `^([a-zA-Z]+)$`
- El nombre solo será válido si empieza y termina por más de una letra de la A a la Z sin acento y está dentro de paréntesis simples: `^(\([a-zA-Z]+\))`.

Combinando ambas soluciones la regex quedaría:

```
^([a-zA-Z]+)$|^(\([a-zA-Z]+\))$
```

En caso que quieras incluir también los acentos podrías usar:

```
^([a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u024F]+)$|^(\([a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u024F]+\))$
```

Finalmente tu función utilizando la función [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) de los arreglos que devuelve `true` si todas las condiciones se cumplen quedaría:

```js
function isValid(listWords) {
  return listWords.every(name => {
    return /^([a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u024F]+)$|^(\([a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u024F]+\))$/.test(name)
})
}


// Pruebas
console.log(`isValid([')name(']) retorna ${isValid([')name('])}`);
console.log(`isValid(['(Ivan)']) retorna ${isValid(['(Ivan)'])}`);
console.log(`isValid(['(Iván)']) retorna ${isValid(['(Iván)'])}`);
console.log(`isValid(['(Ivan))']) retorna ${isValid(['(Ivan))'])}`);
console.log(`isValid(['(Iv]an)']) retorna ${isValid(['(Iv]an)'])}`);
```

Una posible solución sin expresiones regulares sería:

```js
function isValid(listWords) {
    return listWords.every(name => {
        let start = 0;
        let end = name.length;
        if(name[0] === '(') {
            start++;
            if(name[name.length - 1] !== ')') {
                return false;
            }
            end--;
        }

        // Comprueba si cada caracter es una letra valida
        for(let i = start; i < end; i++) {
            if (name[i].toLowerCase() == name[i].toUpperCase()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    })
}

console.log(`isValid([')name(']) retorna ${isValid([')name('])}`);
console.log(`isValid(['(Ivan)']) retorna ${isValid(['(Ivan)'])}`);
console.log(`isValid(['(Iván)']) retorna ${isValid(['(Iván)'])}`);
console.log(`isValid(['Iván']) retorna ${isValid(['Iván'])}`);
console.log(`isValid(['(Ivan))']) retorna ${isValid(['(Ivan))'])}`);
console.log(`isValid(['(Iv]an)']) retorna ${isValid(['(Iv]an)'])}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Aquí te dejo un script que puede solucionarlo.

```javascript
function isValid(list){
    let res = true
    const stringCharacters = ['{','}','[',']'];
    list.forEach((word)=>{
        // Verifica que no tenga llaves, o corchetes
        if (stringCharacters.filter((chr)=>word.includes(chr)).length>0){
            res = false;
            return;
        }
        // Verifica que no tenga paréntisis
        if (!word.includes('(') && !word.includes(')')) return; 

        // Verifica que los paréntisis estén completos y no vacíos
        if (word.endsWith(')') && word[0]==='(' && word.length>2){
            return;
        }
        res = false;
    });
    return res;
};
```

Comment: si pongo una palabra con mas de un paréntesis ejm: (Ivan)) arroja true, debería dar false.

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías también que validar a los que comienzan con `)` en tu condicional:

```js
const list1 = ['Daniel', 'Jose', '(George)', 'Ivan', '(Daniel)'];
const list2 = ['Daniel', 'Jose', '(George)', 'Ivan', '()'];
const list3 = ['Daniel', 'Jose', '(George)', ')Ivan(', '(Daniel)'];
const list4 = ['Daniel', 'Jose', '(George)', '(Ivan', '(Daniel)'];
const list5 = ['Daniel', 'Jose', '(George)', ')Ivan', '(Daniel)'];

function isValid(listWords) {
  let res = true;

  if (listWords[0][0] === ')') res = false;

  listWords.forEach((word) => {
    if (
      (word[0] === '(' || word[0] === ')') &&
      (word[word.length - 1] !== ')' ||
        word.includes('{') ||
        word.includes('[') ||
        word.includes(']') ||
        word.slice(1, word.length).includes('(') ||
        word.length <= 2)
    ) {
      res = false;
    }
  });

  return res;
}

console.log(isValid(list1));
console.log(isValid(list2));
console.log(isValid(list3));
console.log(isValid(list4));
console.log(isValid(list5));
```